# Checking for missing values on dataframe compared to reference dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

I have 2 dataframes which I've imported from a csv file. The first is the reference df with all the answers:

```
             state
0          Alabama
1           Alaska
2          Arizona
```

While the second df has several lists which contain data which I want to cross check with the first df:

```
    column1     column2
0   Arizona  Washington
1  New York    New York
2       NaN        Utah
```

I basically would want a third df which shows me in column1 and column2 the missing items compared to my reference df.
All I found was to check identical df's for differences. But in my case I have less rows in the second df, as well are the items in a different order.

Answer (score 1):

So, through going through several other stack overflow questions, some thinking and some trial and error I found the solution:

```
dict1 = {}
df1 = pandas.DataFrame(dict1)
data_imported = pandas.DataFrame(imported)

columns = ["column1", "column2", "column3"]  # here I am still looking how to add the df's columns in this list, but I assume this shouldn't be too hard.

for column in columns:
    col = []
    for i, row in data_reference.iterrows():
        if row['state'] in data_imported[column].unique():
            pass
        else:
            col.append(row['state'])
    df1[column] = pandas.Series(col)

print(df1)
```

If somebody still comes up with a more elegant version (I read the .iterrows() function is to be avoided), please share.